# I cannot access my simple jsf project after deployement

Tags: jsf, tomcat, deployment, http-status-code-404

I do not understand why I am getting 404 error while trying to access my application

my index.xhtml is in (Web Content)

In my log I have no error 
I created my project using eclipse : web dynamic project :

my url :

```
http://localhost:8080/jsf_getting_started/
```

I tried with eclipse with tomcat (Run On Server).

My web xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>jsf_getting_started</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Whats the name of the jar? Default url would be "http://localhost:8080/name_of_jar" without the suffix .jar. Url has nothing to do with display name, that would be context defined in context.xml instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have set the mapping of the Faces Servlet as `/faces/*` so in order to access to your page and be parsed by this servlet you must access to it like

```
http://localhost:8080/jsf_getting_started/faces/index.xhtml
```

But the problem with the `/faces/*` configuration is that the Faces Servlet will even process non-JSF resources like images, JS, CSS scripts, etc.

The best solution would be to change the mapping to `*.xhtml` and remove all the pages in welcome file list to have only `index.xhtml`. Your web.xml file will look like this (note that I'm just posting the changes made on the parts described in this answer):

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <!-- no need of the other files... -->
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- The relevant URL mapping when using Facelets and JSF -->
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After changing the web.xml file, rebuild your project, make sure to undeploy it from Tomcat Server and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `index.xhtml` in the `welcome-file-list`.

Comment: it does not work, I get a blank page while my index contains :   <h:outputLabel value="hello world" ></h:outputLabel>

Comment: It depends on his "home" file name... not everybody name it index.xhtml.